# How can my client device detect my backend endpoint so that backend functionalities work on the device?

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel

I have a React.js frontend project and Laravel backend project separated. I can access my frontend project via the local host address provided upon running `npm start` so I can see the frontend on a physical device of what I'm working on.

However - When I try to register a new user (backend functionality) on my physical device, it won't allow me to. `php artisan serve`'s running on my backend project and I can successfully login on the browser without any issues so my registration system isn't the issue.

I guess my question is - how can I make it so that my physical device knows that `php artisan serve`'s running so I can access my web app with the localhost address given to me provided by `npm start`?

In other words - how can I make 127.0.0.1:8000 (`php artisan serve`) sync up with 192.168.2.165:3000 (`npm start`)?

I've been following this doc https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/ to proxy but it still isn't working.  I'm wondering if I missed something?  Thanks for taking the time to read.

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(
        '/api/auth/signup',
        createProxyMiddleware({
            target: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000',
            changeOrigin: true,
        })
    );
};
```

Comment: please provide details of the exact problem. "won't allow me to" is neither a clear problem description nor any kind of technical error message. It's unclear specifically what the issue is, especially as we can't see any of the code which is actually performing the action you're talking about.

Comment: @ADyson sorry for the lack of detail.  Registering as a new user doesn't work on client device, the error I'm receiving says `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/signup due to access control checks`.  I don't want to mess with CORS because it's a pain to work with.  It's much better to proxy but that's where I'm falling short.

Comment: ok. So what exactly goes wrong when you try to use the middleware idea? You mentioned it "still isn't working", but again didn't say specifically what's happening in that scenario.

Comment: @ADyson I get the aforementioned error with or without using the middleware idea which's making me think that the middleware isn't being hit even though in the docs it says to not export the `setupProxy.js` file because it gets executed upon running `npm start`.

Comment: Ok I see. To be honest I'm not a react user so I can't really suggest any definite solution. I just commented to try and get the extra details so someone else might be able to help more easily. Can you please use your question's "edit" button and all the information you've just told me to the question itself so it forms a coherent picture.